# How do I define a set of constants that can vary by configuration?

Tags: xamarin

I would like to setup a set of constants that need to vary depending on whether I'm building for dev, qa, or production.  How do I do that with Xamarin?

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to have separate build configurations for each of your environments.  Then user Compile Directives to determine which constant to use.  So something like:

```
#if __DEV
  const string ConnectionString = "Dev Connection String";
#end if
```

**Update:**
Alternatively, what I do on one of my other apps is I present a screen to the user to ask them to select an environment: "DEV", "QA", "STAGE", or "PROD".  And depending on what their choice is, I use the web service address for the respective environment.

Comment: So if I use the configuration manager for the solution, I use the named configurations?

Comment: You could use those, or I would just copy those into a new configuration called something like "Debug-Dev", "Debug-QA", etc.  In your project settings (under Build->Compiler->Define Symbols), create a symbol for "__DEV", "__QA", etc for the respective build configuration.